# __copy_rom_sections_to_ram(); Hangs the MCU

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m, rom

I am working on a project using the Kinetis KEA128 product family of ARM®
Cortex®-M0+. Specifically KEAZ64 variant.

I have a three projects: PRE-LOADER, BOOTLOADER, & APPLICATION.

The Pre-loader executes just fine and jumps to the Bootloader startup code. in the **__arm_start.c** file **__copy_rom_sections_to_ram();** just hangs the MCU and no further operation takes place.
The funny thing is that while using P&E JTAG Debugger, the project works fine and transitions to application. Without the debugger it get's stuck at the said point.

I've tried giving delay, changing address in my linker file, tried copying only 1 byte from ROM to RAM but nothing makes it work.

However, remove the **.romp** section from my linker file the whole project works. The only downside is that I don't get my variables loaded from the NVM.

Any insights regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You!

Edit: 
I understand that I was not able to share the linker file with you guys but thanks for all the input.

I found the solution but the exact cause is unknown.
 1. Previously the **.romp** section was declared to start after the BSS in the **.data** section. 
 2. After moving the **.romp** section above the BSS all issues subsided.

I know this works but I don't understand how would this be much different?

Comment: Can you post the files? We'll need to see the code in order to help.

Comment: Normally I would immediately suspect the stack pointer to not be set correctly, but this is an ARM... could it be that you use two different stacks for the bootloader and the application? Sounds like some sort of RAM corruption or maybe a memory mapping issue.

Comment: It's imp... very difficult to fix such issues by remote text exchange.  TBH, it's very difficult to debug such issues when sitting in front of the hardware with the compiler, linker, environment JTAG etc, esp. if it annoys by not failing under debug :((   'just hangs the MCU' what do you mean by that?  Do you have anything at the abort/trap interrupt targets that issues some kind of error indication?

Comment: Check the addresses of the sections against what your datasheet/manual describes for the address regions. Look particularly for how the read-only address spaces match up to where you're copying to. Perhaps using the jtag shifts the placement of data so the copy-to destination is writable.